# How do I select a file from a native OS file dialogue box in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium-ide

I'm wondering if it's at all possible to select a file from a native OS (Windows, in this case) dialogue box with Selenium IDE.

I've automated the process to open the file dialogue box, however getting Selenium IDE to select the file is confounding me.

Is this possible? I'm sure AHK can take care of this with mouse coords and whatnot, but I'm really trying to stay within the confines of Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a file from a native OS (Windows, in this case) dialogue box is not possible with Selenium IDE, because it identifies only those element which present in page, open in firefox browser.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. Is it possible to execute an AutoIt or AHK script from Selenium IDE to perform these tasks?

Comment: You can used 'selenium RC + AutoIt' to interact with native OS dialogue box